# Create automatic table columns SQL code after a .CSV file in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, csv, import

I have some large (+500 Mbytes) .CSV files that I need to import into a Postgres SQL database.

I am looking for a script or tool that helps me to:

- Generate the table columns SQL CREATE code, ideally taking into account the data in the .CSV file in order to create the optimal data types for each column.
- Use the header of the .CSV as the name of the column.
- It would be perfect if such functionality existed in PostgreSQL or could be added as an add-on.

Thank you very much

Comment: [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/3_power_tools.html#csvsql-and-sql2csv-ultimate-power) `csvsql`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this open source tool called `pgfutter` to create table from your csv file.

[git hub link](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter)

also postgresql has [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) functionality however copy expect that the table already exists.